# types mismatch in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to get number of table's rows in db and output it to console using VBScript, but when I execute following code I get type mismatch error, what should I change in my code to force it execute without errors

```
Dim loop_lim
Const DB_CONNECT_STRING = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=BUG\SQLSERVER2005;Initial Catalog=test;user id ='sa';password='111111'"
Set myConn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set myCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command" )
myConn.Open DB_CONNECT_STRING
Set myCommand.ActiveConnection = myConn
myCommand.CommandText = "select count(*) from oferty o inner join rep_oferta ro on o.indeks = ro.srcdoc inner join rep_pozycje rp on o.indeks = rp.srcdoc"
loop_lim = myCommand.Execute
WScript.Echo loop_lim
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
loop_lim = myCommand.Execute
```

to

```
Set loop_lim = myCommand.Execute
```

because .Execute returns a recordset **object**. Then think about how to get values from the recordset rsp. it's fields.