# Type-mismatch error when closing the splash screen

Tags: vbscript, type-mismatch

I'm using a code from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221145/need-a-vbscript-for-open-a-local-image-file-by-using-command-prompt/1221626#1221626) to display a splash screen during start up of my short bat file that copies some files from the server and takes 15-20 seconds, to prevent multiple clicks by impatient users. I get a type mismatch VBScript error report, line 1, char 1, code 0. The splash window loads normally, but when it should close the error appears and the splash stays on the screen (though the rest of the bat goes on normally).

This is the vbscript code

```
<script language="VBScript">
    Sub Window_OnLoad
        ' Resize and position the window
        width = 500 : height = 400
        window.resizeTo width, height
        window.moveTo screen.availWidth\2 - width\2, screen.availHeight\2 - height\2

        ' Automatically close the windows after 5 seconds
        idTimer = window.setTimeout("vbscript:window.close", 15000)
    End Sub
</script>
```

I think this line

```
idTimer = window.setTimeout("vbscript:window.close", 15000)
```

causes the error.

This only happens on some computers and I haven't really found the common thing with them, they're running either Windows 7 or 8. I found it could do something with [Internet Explorer updates](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/976949/you-receive-a-vbscript-type-mismatch-script-error-message-in-internet), just not sure it applies here as there are no arrays used (AFAIK).

[One of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147422/types-mismatch-in-vbscript) on this site suggests setting `Set` in front of `idtimer`.  -not working for me

Comment: The code snippet you're using is from an HTA. Are you writing an HTA too? Or plain VBScript? Also, please do not paraphrase errors. Show the complete, unaltered error message (error text, number, everything) in your question.

Comment: I'm using the whole hta file. I have an image from the error, but in slovenian - https://i.imgur.com/q5umnlm.png

Comment: Just confirming that "Neuejemanje tipov" = "Type mismatch"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that a simple test HTA file containing your example code works fine on Win7 x64.

Since your type mismatch refers specifically to "vbscript" I'm led to believe that the `vbscript:` part of your timeout call is the issue. The word `vbscript` is being interpreted literally with the colon separating the next statement. Maybe some VBScript runtimes don't have a variable called `vbscript` at the global level.

When I changed the string to be simply "window.close" it worked just fine as well. Give it a try and see if that helps. Additionally, when I change the call to be something blatantly wrong, like "abc:window.close" then I get the Type Mismatch error you described.

[image: Type Mismatch]

I believe doing a `vbscript:` or `javascript:` prefix is only necessary in HTML anchor HREF attributes and the like (although many browsers gracefully allow it anyway for backwards compatibility).

Answer (score 1):

You can check the link below - might provide some insight.

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?342508-How-to-window-close-Resolved